# Почему парсер не записывает то, что нужно, хотя в терминале выдает нужный контент?

Tags: python, парсер

Парсер на python в терминале выдает нужный результат, а вот в бд записывает только последний абзац из найденного. В терминале же отображается весь текст, в котором все как надо.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('ex1.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.executescript("""CREATE TABLE news (id int auto_increment primary key, title text not null, post text not null, url text ); not null""")
def get_html(url): 
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text
def get_total_pages(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    page = soup.find('div', class_='pagination').find_all('a',class_='pagination__num')
    total_pages = page.split('=')[1]

    return int(total_pages)
def get_page_date(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    news = soup.find('div', class_='article-list').find_all('h3', class_='article-list__item-title')
    for new in news:
        try:
            title = new.find('a',class_= 'link_nodecor').text.strip()
            print(title)
        except:
            title = ''
        try:
            url = 'https://example.ru' + new.find('a',class_= 'link_nodecor').get('href')
            print(url)
            post = requests.get(url).text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(post,'lxml')
            articles = soup.find('div',class_='article').find_all('p')
            for article in articles:
                try:
                    post_text = article.text
                    print(post_text)
                except:
                    post_text = ''
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO news VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (title, post_text, url))
            cursor.commit()
        except:
            url = ''

def main(): #конструктор урлов
    base_url = 'https://example.ru/articles?'
    page_part = "page="

    for i in range(1, 100):
        print(i,'итерация')
        url_gen = base_url + page_part + str(i)
        html = get_html(url_gen)
        get_page_date(html)
        print(url_gen)
```

Comment: Заголовок и урлы парсятся как надо, а вот сами статьи - нет.

Comment: Ну так а зачем вывод в терминал и запись в бд стоят в разных местах в коде?

Comment: @Kirillka_Kirillov у вас копи-паста или сами писали код? пройдитесь по функции get_page_date (date - дата/свидание, data - данные; так замечание). В первом try вы кидаете все в терминал, 2й try только пишет в  БД